# mysql query doubt

Tags: mysql, database

my query is as follows:

```
SELECT
r.name
  , r.network
  , r.namestring
  , i.name
  , r.rid
  , i.id
  , d.dtime
  , d.ifInOctets
FROM router AS r
INNER JOIN interface AS i
ON r.rid = i.rid
INNER JOIN 1278993600_1_60 AS d
ON i.id = d.id
AND dtime BETWEEN 1279027200 AND 1279029000
WHERE r.network = "ITPN"
AND i.status = "active"
WHERE i.id BETWEEN 1418 AND 1518
```

There is the problem when I add the last part `WHERE i.id BETWEEN 1418 AND 1518`
 how I could add extra condition here?
Any help???
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT r.name, r.network, r.namestring, i.name, r.rid, i.id, d.dtime,
       d.ifInOctets
FROM router AS r
INNER JOIN interface AS i
ON r.rid = i.rid
INNER JOIN 1278993600_1_60 AS d
ON i.id = d.id
AND d.dtime BETWEEN 1279027200 AND 1279029000
WHERE r.network = "ITPN"
AND i.status = "active"
AND i.id BETWEEN 1418 AND 1518
```

Comment: I tried that. goes into some kind of infinite loop and the query never stops

Comment: @jillika iyer, We need table structures for providing answer, may you update question and add definition for tables: routes, interface and 1278993600_1_60

Comment: @jillika iyer: sure you don't have any typos in your query? It should be working

Comment: SQL statement like that can't go into infinate loops. How many records are in each table?

Comment: thanks a lot.worked.i was querying through some 100000 data set. so it was crashing :P

Answer (score 1):

You have two `WHERE` clauses, and only one is allowed. See Michael's answer for the correct syntax.